# Get YouTube Profile Icon From YouTube Username

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I'm making a small application, and would like to integrate a YouTube section.

I already have a way of getting the channel name seen in the URL buy using:

```
<?php echo $user['username']; ?>
```

The username is always the YouTube channel name. Now that YouTube is hooked up with Google+, the icons are based on Google plus.

herefore, the link to a channels icon isn't simply `http://data.youtube.com/youtubeusername/icon.jpg` or something (that is made up).

The icon URL is more like:

[image]

> https://yt3.ggpht.com/-wJihGYNAGRE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ZVJ8gCn1JcU/s100-c-k-no/photo.jpg

I'm looking for someone who can tell me how to retrieve a channel's icon based on their YouTube username, and how to implement that into my existing page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the users image by using a url like this:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/communitychannel
```

You can get just the username and image thumbnail by appending a query string as described in the partial responses api: **?fields=yt:username,media:thumbnail**

You can get the response in json format to use easily in javascript by appending: **&alt=json-in-script&format=5**

You can also specify a callback to execute when the response has loaded by appending: **&callback=showImage**

Your url now looks like this:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/communitychannel?fields=yt:username,media:thumbnail&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showImage
```

To use this in a page put it in a script tag like so:

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src="your_url"/>
```

and the callback should look like this:

```
function showImage(data)
{
  var name= data.entry.yt$username.$t;
  var url = data.entry.media$thumbnail.url;
  $(document).append("<img src='"+ url +"'/>");
}
```

You must make sure that the showImage callback function is defined before you load the data.

Comment: Thanks, now how do I implement this into an HTML <img> tag?

Comment: you can add a image tag with ID lets say le call it yimg
 HTML
    <img id='yimg' src=''/>;
 javascript
function showImage(data)
{
  var name= data.entry.yt$username.$t;
  var url = data.entry.media$thumbnail.url;
  $('yimg').attr('src',url);
}

Comment: Perhaps it's with the <img> tag?

Comment: plz check 
<?php
$data =  doCURL('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/communitychannel?fields=yt:username,media:thumbnail&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showImage'); 
$data = str_replace('// API callback','',$data);
$data = str_replace('showImage(','',$data);
$data = str_replace('"}}});','"}}}',$data);
$data = json_decode($data,true);
echo '<img src="'.$data['entry']['media$thumbnail']['url'].'" />';

function doCURL($url){
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
  ));
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 return $response;
 }
?>

Comment: Sadly, this is no longer supported.